# How do I properly use async in my useEffect method?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code below that

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      setQuestions(snapshot.val());
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    })
    console.log(questiona);
  }, []);
```

The output is first questiona, then snapshot.val().

```
null //questiona
(15) objects //snapshot.val()
```

So since the log shows that the second console.log is being executed before the first one, I now know I need to turn this into a async function. So I changed the code above to how it is below

```
  useEffect(() => {
    let database = firebase.database();
    database.ref().on('value', (snapshot) => {
      async () => {
        await setQuestions(snapshot.val());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        console.log('hit');
      }
    })
    console.log(questiona);
  }, []);
```

The problem is that I'm misusing the async keyword because the code inside the async block is not being called at all. I have a console.log in it that should output hit when executed but it never shows on the console. How do I properly use async and await in this block?

Comment: How about moving `async` up to the `(snapshot) => {` or immediately invoke the `async` function with an IIFE `(async () => { ... })()` if the `.on("value", ` callback must not be async?

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you! Moving it up to be before ```(snapshot) ``` worked perfectly. Thanks again matex